# Null value when trying to retrieve from other class

Tags: java, android

somehow my mind is not working and mild fever didn't help.

I have the following code, batteryLevel here shows the correct value - 50.

```
public class AlarmEventService extends Service {    
    static String batteryLevel; 
    ...
    int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0); 
    batteryLevel = String.valueOf(level); 
    Log.i(APP_TAG, batteryLevel);
}
```

Why in my outside call when I get value of AlarmEventService.batteryLevel the value is null?

```
public class AlarmEventReceiverWake extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    ...
    Log.i(APP_TAG, "Battery Level " + AlarmEventService.batteryLevel);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Also, you shouldn't be trying to access `static` fields of a `Service` in this way. What is triggering the `BroadcastReceiver` and why does it need to know what the battery level is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have presented of the code, there is no reason why it shouldnt work as expected. It may be possibile that:

- Another variable named batteryLevel may be declared locally, thereby not assigning the value to the global version.
- the value of batteryLevel may be reset after your initial call.

Make sure that the statement:

```
batteryLevel = String.valueOf(level);
```

is actually being called *before*

```
Log.i(APP_TAG, "Battery Level " + AlarmEventService.batteryLevel);
```

Comment: There's also the possibility that the process was killed in between (maybe you also mean that with "reset").

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility. Overall, encapsulation is the way to go here to see where the variable is being modified.

Comment: @Reimeus : **"...there is no reason why it shouldnt work as expected."** - That's not actually true. The Android `Service` class is a 'special case' class and instances of `Service` are maintained by the OS itself. A `Service` can either be 'started' or 'bound to' by another Android component (or components). The life-cycle of a `Service` is indeterminate and may be long or short running. Any class which extends `Service` should never expose `static` fields or methods and this is almost certainly why the OP's approach is failing.

Comment: I fully agree. Using static access like this is never a good idea.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think because it is a service and therefore the static fields did not get expose.